# TextView gets centered when growing out of space

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I have a very basic `ConstraintLayout` with a `TextView` and `Button` with the following requirements:

1. The `ConstraintLayout` width should be the size of the largest width of `TextView` and `Button` (works already)
2. When the `TextView` isn't the largest view in terms of width, it should be aligned to the end (currently aligned in the middle when `Button` is larger)
3. The height of the `ConstraintLayout` should be the `TextView` height + `Button` height, currently it has extra padding

It looks like this now:

[image]

and this is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout">

        <Button
                android:text="ssdsa ddsdsda"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
                android:text="texttttttttttttt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `xml` file from `TextView` just remove `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"` it will work as per your requirement.

For remove extra padding in the bottom also remove `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` this line from `TextView`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout">

        <Button
            android:text="ssdsa ddsdsda"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:text="texttttttttttttt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```